# query chain of models in Django

Tags: django

I have three models for countries, provinces and cities. one of URLs includes the city name where a post should go. I could get the name of the city through the URL . In view function, I could find the city name and then I could find the country which the city is belong to. Now, I want to list all cities under this country. My question is how can I do this where there is no direct relation between city and country. The city is related to the province and the province related to the country. The list I want should includes all cities inside the country regardless of the province. How can I do this? is there any possible solution rather than make direct relation between city and country model? 
Note: I could get the country ID through the variable post_city. The country ID for selected city was 3. Therefor, I want all of cities that are under the country that has an ID of 3.
Example: through the URL: I got post_city variable as Los Angeles. Hence, I want all cities in the USA regardless of state of California. Another example, If the post_city variable was London, then, I want all cities in Britain regardless of the province. 
the models I have are as follow:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.country_name)


class Province(models.Model):
    country_id = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    province_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.province_name)

class City(models.Model):
    province_name = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def Country(self):
        return self.province_name.country_id.country_name
```

the view function as follow:

```
def list_page(request, post_city):

    p_c = City.objects.filter(city_name__iexact=post_city).get()
    p_p = p_c.province_name
    p_country = p_p.country_id

    pp=City.objects.all()

    print(pp)

    context = {
    'post_city' : post_city,

    'all_p_cities': all_p_cities,

    }
    return render(request, 'path/to/list_page.html', context )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple related model lookups by using several `__` parts in the lookup argument name.

```
cities_in_narnia = City.objects.filter(province_name__country_id__country_name='Narnia')
```

Read more in the Django docs: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

As a side note. There are some naming conventions you can use that will make your code more readable, especially when seeking help from the online community.

```
class City(models.Model):
    # foreign key fields should be the snake_case or lower case name of the related model class
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # there's no need to prefix field or attribute names with the class name 
    # City.city_name is superfluous. City.name is perfectly clear.  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    # methods and attributes should also be snake_case, only use CapitalCase for class names.
    @property
    def country_name(self):
        return self.province.country.name
```

If you follow these naming conventions, the filter lookup will also be readable and concise.

```
cities_in_narnia = City.objects.filter(province__country__name='Narnia')
```

Comment: Thanks for response. this gives me empty query set. this is not what I want. I added example to clarify what I want to do. Example: through the URL: I got post_city variable as Los Angeles. Hence, I want all cities in the USA regardless of state of California. Another example, If the post_city variable was London, then, I want all cities in Britain regardless of the province.

Comment: If you get an empty queryset, then the country name or city name is presumably spelled differently from your input. Or maybe you don't have the country of Narnia in your database? An empty queryset demonstrates that the query is valid. If it was invalid, django would raise an exception instead.

Comment: Further to this, you should look at better naming conventions for your relations. The point that I wanted to stress though is that since you are searching for locations in the URL like this ` /someurl/New York` you should definately consider adding a slug field for the name of the location and ensure that you search of that instead. New York slug -> new-york makes your URL look like this `some-url/new-york`

Comment: I will do what you suggest. Thank you so much